# Can you load local content with awesomium or chromium using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, chromium, awesomium

Using awesomium (or chromium), is it possible to load content from the file system?

Maybe by using ajax or some other method?

Comment: What do you mean by "load"? Query a rest service? Display an HTML page?

Comment: For example: If there is a file in the local file system with the url `file://file.txt`. Can I load the contents of that file into a javascript variable?

Comment: Without the user giving you access to it, I very much doubt it. If you control the client system, You could easily read it with C# and invoke a javascript function with the contents though.

Comment: excellent, thank you. I think that would suffice as an answer.

Comment: out of curiosity, this javascript bridge, is it two way? can i invoke c# functions from javascript?

Comment: Yes, see the links in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites in Awesomium/Chromium, just like normal websites, operate in a sandbox. This means that without the user explicitly "giving" you a file, there is **no way** to access it.

However, your WPF application could easily *read* such a file and pass its contents to the web page using the awesomium control.

You use `CallJavascriptFunction`:

```
JSValue fileText = new JSValue(fileText);
webView.CallJavascriptFunction("someMethod", fileText );
```

Related (and where I got the base of that code from): [calling Javascript from c# using awesomium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762876/calling-javascript-from-c-sharp-using-awesomium)

If you want to go the *other* way, see [Can I call application methods from JavaScript in Awesomium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280727/can-i-call-application-methods-from-javascript-in-awesomium)